# Oracle SQL Developer is not working properly with Mac M1

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a Mac M1 Max with MacOS Monterey and recently downloaded the Oracle SQL Developer for Mac OSX with JDK 11 included. The installation was simple and straightforward, and I was able to run the application without any issues at first. I even set up a Git repository. However, I have noticed that sometimes when I open it, it becomes unresponsive and I have to delete and re-download the application to get it running again. This has been happening repeatedly.

I was wondering if anyone has faced a similar issue and if there is a solution to fix this problem

Run Oracle SQL on Mac M1 without it becoming unresponsive